# Minimum $\Re$ on the circle

Tags: complex-analysis, cauchy-integral-formula

How to calculate and what is its value of the minimum of $\Re(z^{-2})$ on the circle:
$$ \gamma=\left\{ t+\frac{t}{2}e^{i\omega} \Bigg|0\leq\omega \leq2\pi  \right\}. $$

I would appreciate any kind of help!

Comment: Is $t{}{}$ real?

Comment: Yes! I apologise for not specifying!

Comment: You can say WLOG, $t=1$ !

Comment: Can't you evaluate $z^{-2}$ ?

Comment: Note that $\Re(z^{-2})= \frac{\Re z^2}{|z|^4}$ (since $\Re z^2= \Re \bar z^2$) and since we can take $t=2$ wlog we get the denominator $(5+4\cos \omega)^2$ and the numerator is $3+4\cos \omega +2\cos^2 \omega$ so one has to look at $\frac{3+4y+2y^2}{(5+4y)^2}, -1 \le y \le 1$ etc

Comment: there is also a theory solution using the substitution $w=z-2$ so we need to minimize $\Re {(w+2)^{-2}}$ on the unit circle, hence if $x$ is a minimum for it, one must have $xf'(x) <0$ where $f(w)=(w+2)^{-2}$ so $x/(x+2)^3 >0$ or reversing $x^2+6x+12+8\bar x =c >0$ since $|x|=1$ and taking imaginary parts we get $\Im x^2-2 \Im x=0$ which easily gives $\sin \theta =0$ or $\cos \theta =1$ where $x=e^{i\theta}$ so $\theta =0, \pi$ and only $\theta =0$ gives the expected $1/9$ minimum

Comment: @Conrad could you explain to me this reversing part? And thank you!

Comment: $x/(x+2)^3 >0$ iff $(x+2)^3/x >0$ but then expanding the cubic and noting that $1/x=\bar x$ we get precisely $x^2+6x+12+8\bar x =c >0$ and if one needs to understand why at a minimum for $\Re f$ we need to have $xf'(x) <0$, the idea is that we have a maximum modulus for $g=e^{-f}$ there and use that $\partial g/\partial \theta =0, \partial g/\partial r >0$ which after some manipulations gives $xg'(x)/g(x) >0$ and that immediately translates to $xf'(x) <0$ (that includes the important fact that $xf'(x)$ is real of course)